# Javascript DATE from SQL Server: Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, charts, canvasjs

So I am currently making a line chart that it's date will be called from my db.
The Problem is that the DAYS are kept repeated like this.
[image]

I want to keep the days single only like this rather than doubled.
: 11Feb2018    12Feb2018    13Feb2018     14Feb2018

Javascript(Views):

```
dataPoints: [
 <?php foreach ($result1 as $row) { ?>
  <?php echo'{x:new Date('.$row->data1.','.$row->data2.','.$row->data3.'), 
y:'.$row->data4.'},'?>
 <?php } ?>
]
```

Controller:

```
$data['result1'] = $this->madminpathologyweekly->get_result1()->result();
$this->load->view('vadminpathologyweekly',$data);
```

Model:

```
public function get_result1() {
    $sql = "SELECT year as data1,month_of_the_year - 1 as data2, day_of_the_month as data3,";
    $sql .= "COUNT(test_id) as data4 from TBLSUBMITTEDREQUEST group by year ,month_of_the_year, day_of_the_month";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: so group by day_of_the_month is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

So I did a deeper research and I found out that I missed an interval type: and interval: in axis x like this.

```
axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "DD MMMM YYYY",
        intervalType: "day",
        interval: 1,
       },
```

Cheers guys. I've already solved it. Thanks for your time.